# 1 Timer vs multiple timers (async)

Tags: timer, minecraft

I was wondering what is more efficient.
1 Timer that does a lot or multiple timers that all do their own small thing.

So the context of what it is needed for:
I am making a plugin for Minecraft and it has to do with spells, when a players casts a spell I make a new instance of a spell, it has to do something every single tick. 
So I want to know what is best, create for all the spells a async timer and as soon as it is done, stop the timer, and clear all references to the spell so it gets deleted automatically by the garbage collector.
OR
Create the spell, put it in a static list in my handler, and let the handler have 1 timer that checks for every single spell.
(there can be over 200 spells active in a second... but that is the worst case scenerio :P)

Kind regards,
runefist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the details of the Minecraft run-time, but in general, each timer has an overhead, typically where the run-time passes the control over to your code.  So in general, a single timer will be more efficient than multiple timers.  The actual implementation in Minecraft might however mitigate this in some undefined, clever way, but I doubt that.

Additionally, creating resources on the fly and letting a garbage collector deal with that will also add additional load to your configuration.

So, for a solely performance point of view, a single, static timer will most certainly be more efficient.  How much more efficient and at what additional implementation cost I cannot tell, and will possibly vary wildly depending on your existing code.